# NFS and mounted subdirectories

Tags: nfs, mount

I have two physical disks mounted as such:

> sda1 -> /mnt/storage
>
> sdb1 -> /mnt/storage/homes

I've exported /mnt/storage as an NFS share.  The client sees all of the contents of /mnt/storage, but it does not show the contents of sdb1 when browsing the /mnt/storage/homes folder.  It does display any contents within /mnt/storage/homes before sdb1 is mounted there.  Is this a limitation of NFS or are there mount parameters that can be used to follow the other mount as I was expecting?

Answer (score 2):

*The client sees all of the contents of /mnt/storage, but it does not show the contents of sdb1 when browsing the /mnt/storage/homes folder. It does display any contents within /mnt/storage/homes before sdb1 is mounted there.*

This doesn't make sense. There **shouldn't be any** contents of /mnt/storage/homes before sdb1 is mounted there, right?

Let's ignore the NFS client for a minute and just focus on the server.

1. ## Stop your NFS server, how to do this depends on your linux distribution
2. umount /mnt/storage/homes
3. umount /mnt/storage
4. ls /mnt/storage
5. mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/storage
6. ls /mnt/storage
7. ls /mnt/storage/homes
8. mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/storage/homes
9. ls /mnt/storage/homes

When you list the directory contents in step 4 and step 7, there should be nothing displayed. The files and folders you expect to be in each mountpoint should appear in step 6 and step 9.

The answer to your question is that you have to export both /mnt/storage and /mnt/storage/homes. If you only have a single client, you can use the *nohide* option on /mnt/storage/homes to avoid needing to explicitly mount it on the client. See the *exports* man page for more details. That said, I'd recommend avoiding *nohide* and mounting both filesystems for clarity.

Comment: all the ls commands show what I'd expect on the server.  Because the client always showed /mnt/storage/homes as empty, I unmounted it, put an empty file in /mnt/storage/homes/test and remounted /mnt/storage/homes.  Running "ls /mnt/storage/homes" on the server shows the contents of sdb1.  Running "ls /mnt/storage/homes" on the client displays the "test" file as the only contents.  I tested this on two CentOS servers and both have the same behavior.

Comment: Okay, I thought you might have just been doing that as a test but I wanted to be sure.